How to use monotonically_increasing_id() in DuckDB
I'm trying to use one of the pyspark function monotonically_increasing_id() through DuckDB sql query and i'm getting duckdb.duckdb.CatalogException: Catalog Error: Scalar Function with name monotonically_increasing_id does not exist!
Below is the code that i use to auto generate a number using monotonically_increasing_id() in duckDB:
SQL_QUERY_SRC_JOIN = "SELECT monotonically_increasing_id() AS col1,a.* from (SELECT col2 FROM df_cust UNION  SELECT col3 FROM df_branch UNION SELECT col4 FROM df_rep) as a order by col1"

src_df = duckdb.sql(SQL_QUERY_SRC_JOIN).pl()

'df_' represents polars dataframe.
Can someone please help me how we can implement this using duckdb?
Thanks

Are you trying to add a row number? i.e. select row_number() over () as col1

Yes i'm trying to add a row number but i need to match the transformed value (row number) in the target system which uses monotonically_increasing_id() in its transformation logic

Hm, ok. monotonically_increasing_id() doesn't exist in DuckDB though - from what I can see it appears to only exist in Spark.
